# Retrieve checkboxlist value in c#.net

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net

I want to retrieve checkboxlist value from my SQL Server 2005 database, where I have a table with a column `car` that contains n values like `BMW,Jaguar,Royal`.

Now I want to retrieve them for specific checkbox in checkboxlist; I tried:

```
for (int x = 0; x < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; x++) { 
  if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[x].ToString()) {
    checkedListBox1.Text = sdr.GetString(16).Split(","); 
   } 
 }
```

but it is not working. I get following error:

> *The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params
>   char[])' has some invalid arguments*

This is the SQL query:

```
select 
    RegisterNo, RegistrationDate, Stimulation, PationName,
    DateOfBirth, ContactNo, Occupat‌ion, Age, Sex, Chief_Complain,
    Investigation_Result, PastHistoryAny, Physical_Examinati‌on,
    Ref_By_Doctor, Medications, Prognosis, Electro_Therapy,
    Neuro_Rehabilitation, Ortho‌​_Rehabilitation,
    Cardio_Pulmonery_Rehabilitation, Sports_Rehabilitation 
from 
    Physio_cureTable 
where 
    RegisterNo = @RegisterNo 
    and Syncoperation <> 'D
```

Comment: @Aties: Are you sure that the mentioned table schema is related to this sql query? There is no `car` column and i doubt if this table contains cars at all ;) Btw, the column which you retrieve in ADO.NET via `reader.GetString` is `Neuro_Rehabilitation` not car.

Comment: ya sir that true but i give u one example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now that we have a **useful** error message (and not just *it doesn't work*), we can help.

The error message seems pretty clear:

> *The best overloaded method match for **'string.Split(params char[])'** has some invalid arguments*

So check your call to `.Split()` - as you can see from the error message, it expects one or multiple **characters** for its separator(s). But you are **not** providing one or multiple characters - you're passing in a **string** and that's **NOT** a character....

```
checkedListBox1.Text = sdr.GetString(16).Split(",");
```

Accordingly, change your call to actually pass in a `,` as a **character** (in C# expressed by **single quotes**):

```
checkedListBox1.Text = sdr.GetString(16).Split(',');
```

and then it should work, I believe.

**Update:** your second main problem is the fact that `.Split()` returns an **array of string** - not just a single string. But you're trying to assign that array of string to a `.Text` property which is just one string. So what do you want to do with those 10 strings you get back? You need to find a way to assign them to something that can hold **multiple strings**).

If I interpret your code correctly, you most likely want to load that comma-delimited entry from the database table, and then populate the `CheckListBox.Items` with those strings - right?

Then you need something like:

```
// clear the list of items 
checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();

// parse the loaded comma-separated string into array of individual strings
string[] stringsFromDatabase = sdr.GetString(16).Split(","); 

// load those strings into .Items for checklistbox
foreach(string str in stringsFromDatabase)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

Comment: marc_s sir still error coming Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string' E:\Winform n console\PhysioCure\PhysioCure\PhysioCure\Form1.cs 488 48 PhysioCure

Comment: showing Error 6 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' E:\Winform n console\PhysioCure\PhysioCure\PhysioCure\Form1.cs 497 25 PhysioCure
error on checkedListBox4.CheckedItems[x].ToString() code

Comment: @Aties: updated my response with that *I believe* you want - your question isn't very clear on this....

Comment: thank you very very much marc_s it working thank you very much n happy new year dear :)